# 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] on trying to install google-chrome in databricks spark driver

Tags: linux, selenium-chromedriver, databricks, google-chrome-headless

We are installing google-chrome-stable in databricks cluster using apt-get install. Which has been working fine for a long time, but since the past few days it has started to fail intermittently.

The following is the code that we run.

`````
%sh
sudo curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub| apt-key add
sudo echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo apt-get -y update apt-get -y --fix-missing install google-chrome-stable````
`````

The following is the error we see.

```
Get:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages[1,075 B]
Fetched 2,886 B in 1s (4,041 B/s)
Reading package lists...
grep: E: Aborting install: No such file or directory E: Failed to fetch
```

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_245.44ubuntu3.18_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Aborting install.

was trying to reinstall the package if failure occured using the follow code

```
%sh
i=0
while true;
echo "inside while loop" 
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:vikoadi/ppa
sudo apt-get -y --fix-missing install google-chrome-stable
do 
if [ $(google-chrome --version| grep -c "Google Chrome") -gt 0 ]; then
 echo "chrome installed"
 break;
 else
 echo "chrome not installed trying another attempt"
 echo "sleeping"
 sleep 10000 
fi
done
```

But the above logic did not work because - while loop breaks on installation failure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking to see if IPv6 is disabled on your network connection, and if so to enable it and then see if updating runs cleanly.

I had similar issues and found that various URLs used in the aptitude updater ( apt / apt-get ) did not resolve to anything from my computer, but after looking at the DNS I found that it only had AAAA IPv6 records and did not have records set for IPv4.